# SQL Server : EXEC command while altering proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, metadata, alter

I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC myPROC
    @myInput NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTABLE

    -- I want this next command to run not to be stored for later execution.  
    EXEC RegisterProcSomewhere
END
GO
```

Is there a preferred way to do this? Essentially I want to collect metadata on my procedure when I `CREATE/ALTER` them.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a DDL trigger

Answer (score 0):

Call it outside the proc to execute it immediately.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC myPROC
@myInput NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM myTABLE

 -------------------------------

END
GO

--I want this next command to run not to be stored for later execution. 
EXEC RegisterProcSomewhere
```